# Alternatives for VS Android emulator?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, android-emulator

I can't have VS Android emulator (Windows 10 Home do not support Hyper-V) and do you know some others emulators for Visual Studio (I programming in C++ / OpenGL) and if you know how I can Install it to work with Visual Studio?

Comment: Check Xamarin's Android emulator, but not sure if it works for VS. It is very likely that you will have to upgrade your Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the standard Android AVD emulators with Intel HAXM or [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) which is a paid product.